# Systemd: unknown lvalue 'User' in section 'Unit'

Tags: systemd, ubuntu-16.04

A couple weeks a go I moved from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and found my Upstart script no longer worked, so feeling adventurous I managed to create a Systemd script that worked instead.

But I'm having a couple issues still.

`[/etc/systemd/system/ss13_server.service:3] Unknown lvalue 'User' in section 'Unit'`

This is my Systemd Script:

```
[Unit]
Description=ss13_server
User=ss13
[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/ss13/ss13
ExecStart=/usr/local/byond/bin/DreamDaemon /home/ss13/ss13/baystation12.dmb 25565 -trusted
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=90s
```

It is meant to run the command 
`/usr/local/byond/bin/DreamDaemon /home/ss13/ss13/baystation12.dmb 25565 -trusted`
within `/home/ss13/ss13` as the user `ss13`
and then rerun that command if the process dies.

As far as I can tell it does that pretty well, except for the error `[/etc/systemd/system/ss13_server.service:3] Unknown lvalue 'User' in section 'Unit'`

Which leads me to suspect it is not running as the correct user.

I used a website that shows the commands from upstart and the alternatives for systemd and the correct area they go into.

Anyway, any help is useful,
Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`User` should be in section `[Service]`.